# Vscode php suggestion is not accurate

Tags: visual-studio-code

When trying to access an object with the -> operator to see what methods it has, Vscode shows me all php build in function like rand, acos, str_replace including the object methods. For me it look like a bug. But what I want to see when accessing an object only its methods. Is there any way that fixes that?

#### Vscode Output

[image]

[image]

#### Expected Output

[image]

Comment: It looks like VSCode doesn't know what type of object is in `$this->invoiceRepo`. Make sure that property is either typehinted or has a @var docblock comment.

Comment: no it is typehinted and its methods are show among the suggestion list, but it is overwhelming to scroll the whole list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install some extensions from vscode extension market, such as PHP Debug and PHP Intelephense.

You can also use github copilot by installing the extension as well

Comment: I have already these extensions

Comment: and copilot? try copilot